# Calculating reactions to load on a beam

Tags: beginner, ruby, physics

I am new to Ruby and would like some help with re-factoring my code.

```
class Beam
def initialize 
    puts "Please specify span of beam"
    @span = gets.chomp.to_f
    puts "How many number of point loads do you want?"
    @pointLoadNos = gets.chomp.to_i
    @pointLoad = Array.new(@pointLoadNos)
    @pointLoadDistFromLeft = Array.new(@pointLoadNos)
    @pointLoadDistFromRight = Array.new(@pointLoadNos)
    @magnitude = Array.new(@pointLoadNos) 
    @reaction = Array.new(2,0)
end
def setValues
    count = 0
    while count < @pointLoadNos
        puts "At what dist should point load #{count+1} be placed from left?"
        @pointLoadDistFromLeft[count] = gets.chomp.to_f
        if @pointLoadDistFromLeft[count] > @span
            puts "Dist of Point Load #{count+1} From Left should be less than span length of beam"
        else    
            puts "Magnitude of point load #{count+1} should be?"
            @magnitude[count] = gets.chomp.to_f
            @pointLoadDistFromRight[count] = (@span - @pointLoadDistFromLeft[count])
            count += 1
        end
    end
end
def calReactions
    i = 0
    while i < @pointLoadNos
        @reaction[0] += (@pointLoadDistFromLeft[i]*@magnitude[i])/@span
        @reaction[1] += (@pointLoadDistFromRight[i]*@magnitude[i])/@span
        i += 1
    end
    puts "Reaction at Left: #{@reaction[0]}"
    puts "Reaction at Left: #{@reaction[1]}"
end
end

beam = Beam.new
beam.setValues
beam.calReactions
```

Comment: For future reference, please give some background/context on what your code's supposed to accomplish. Yes, we can glean it from reading the code, but a simple "This class models a beam (as in a bridge or building) and calculates the forces exerted at its ends by an arbitrary number of point loads. It prompts the user for input values." would help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should **not** get user input from inside your `Beam` class. This ties it to the console and makes automated testing more difficult. A layered architecture is more suitable :

```
# The Beam class is only concerned by business logic.
# Notice how the logic and workflow are clear and readable,
# and how easy you it would be to write tests for it.
# 
class Beam

  attr_reader :span

  def initialize( span )
    @span        = span.to_f
    @load_points = {}
  end

  def add_load_point( distance, magnitude )
    distance, magnitude = distance.to_f, magnitude.to_f
    if distance < 0 || distance > span || @load_points[distance]
      raise ArgumentError, 'invalid load point' 
    end
    @load_points[distance] = magnitude
  end 

  def reactions
    @load_points.inject( left: 0, right: 0 ) do |hash, (distance, magnitude)|
      hash[:left]  += distance          * magnitude / span
      hash[:right] += (span - distance) * magnitude / span
      hash
    end
  end

end


# this module is an interface between your class and the user
# via the console. Notice that this module (could be a class,
# does not matter) is only concerned about asking questions,
# adapting user input to feed the Beam class interface, and 
# formatting output.
# 
module BeamConsole

  # here we chose to move all questions to the user to methods,
  # and name these methods with an exclamation mark at the end
  #
  def self.invoke
    beam = Beam.new( span? )
    begin
      beam.add_load_point( distance?, magnitude? )
    rescue ArgumentError => e
      puts "Invalid parameters for load point. Please retry." ; retry   
    end while more? 
    format_reactions( beam.reactions )
  end

  private #=================================================================== 

  # adapted from @nakilon's answer, tail-recursive variant
  def self.prompt( msg )
    output = gets.strip!
    return output unless output.empty? 
    prompt( msg )
  end

  def self.span?
    prompt( 'Please specify span of beam' ).to_f
  end

  def self.more?
    answer = prompt( 'Do you want to add points ? (y/n)' )
    answer = prompt( 'please answer by y or n' ) unless answer =~ /^[y|n]$/
    answer == 'y'
  end

  def self.distance?
    prompt( 'At what distance should the point be placed from left?' ).to_f
  end

  def self.magnitude?
    prompt( 'Magnitude should be?' ).to_f
  end

  def self.format_reactions( reactions )
    puts "Reaction on the left is  : %.4f" % reactions[:left]
    puts "Reaction on the right is : %.4f" % reactions[:right]
  end
end
```

This may seem overkill, but separating concerns is the core of OOP. With this approach, you'll end up with a `Beam` class devoid of any responsability concerning user interaction, and that's a good thing : you want your class to perform business logic before anything else.

This way, your code will be more readable (no logic riddled with prompts), so more maintainable, but also more *reusable*. Imagine that one day you want to allow users to perform calculations from a web page : you could not reuse your `Beam` class if it is tied to the console, but you could if you separated responsibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I would write something like:

```
class Beam
    def prompt msg
        # a bit kung-fu, sorry
        puts msg while gets.strip!.empty?
        yield $_
    end
    def initialize 
        @span = prompt "Please specify span of beam", &:to_f
        @pointLoadNos = prompt "How many number of point loads do you want?", &:to_i
        @pointLoad = []
        @pointLoadDistFromLeft = []
        @pointLoadDistFromRight = []
        @magnitude = []
    end
    def setValues
        @pointLoadNos.times do |count|
            while 0 > @pointLoadDistFromRight[count] = @span - @pointLoadDistFromLeft[count] =
                  prompt("At what dist should point load #{count + 1} be placed from left?", &:to_f)
                puts "Dist of Point Load #{count + 1} From Left should be less than span length of beam"
            end
            @magnitude[count] = prompt "Magnitude of point load #{count + 1} should be?", &:to_f
        end
    end
    def calReactions
        @reaction = [0, 0]
        @magnitude.zip(@pointLoadDistFromLeft, @pointLoadDistFromRight) do |mag, left, right|
            @reaction[0] += (left * mag) / @span
            @reaction[1] += (right * mag) / @span
        end
        puts "Reaction at Left: #{@reaction[0]}"
        puts "Reaction at Right: #{@reaction[1]}"
    end
end

beam = Beam.new
beam.setValues
beam.calReactions
```

See [this](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/Block-Parameters-And-Yielding.htm) and [this](http://www.potstuck.com/2011/08/06/ruby-symbols-instead-of-blocks/) - when you pass a block, you don't have to catch it into argument, but can just use Ruby's keyword `yield`. Also instead of describing a block as a proc, you can use `&:method` notation.